# Success with any usefull value

Tags: scala

I have some code that may generate exceptions if there are any of them, and returns nothing if it's successfully ran.

My question is : is there a best way to handle such cases ?

Actually, I'm using a `Try[Unit]` that returns `Failure(exception)` or `Success(Unit)` but I'm wondering if this the right way to do ? if there are any best practice ? or a better way to use in such situation ?

Here's an overview of my code :

```
val result: Try[Unit] = 
  Try {
    //some code that may generate exceptions
    Success(Unit)
  }
```

Edit 1 : As mentioned in the accepted answer and in the comments the way I'm using the `Try` is wrong. The `Try` wrap the result in a `Success` and the exceptions in a `Failure` so it's meaningless to return a `Success`, we have to return the result directly instead. In this particular case return `()` as shown here :

```
val result: Try[Unit] = 
  Try {
    //some code that may generate exceptions
    ()
  }
```

Comment: That `.transform()` isn't doing anything for you. The result of the `Try` block is already a `Success` or `Failure`.

Comment: @jwvh I've just edited my question so that it would be more clearer.  the `transform` is just an example. my problem is how to represent a `Success` that haven't ant useful value. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You're still not using `Try` correctly. You don't need to state `Success()` or `Failure()` directly. That's what `Try` provides automatically. Do this `Try{println("go")}` in the REPL and see what you get. If the `Try` code doesn't encounter an exception then it will return a `Success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing it as `Try[Unit]` seems to be the way to go, here's what the repl has to show about it:

```
scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> val a: Try[Unit] = Try { 2 + 2 }
a: scala.util.Try[Unit] = Success(())

scala> a.toOption // check that there's really nothing in the returned value
res0: Option[Unit] = Some(())

scala> val b = Try { 2 + 2 }
b: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(4)
```

Please note 2 more things:

1. as stated in the comments on your question, the way you use `Try` in your code is wrong, I'll put a correct example below.
2. you can also return Unit, but the way you do it is also wrong, what you are actually returning is the `Unit` companion object, see below for the right way to do:

...

```
val result: Try[Unit] =
  Try {
    //some code that may generate exceptions
    () // this is how you "return" unit
  }
```